# How do you make Bastille work and secure Ubuntu 12.04? It doesnt work for me `sudo bastille -x`

Tags: security

I was able to install bastille from the normal repositories and then run the GUI. After going through the options and clicking OK to apply, it showed these errors.

Do you know why Bastille wont work on Ubuntu 12.04?

```
NOTE:    Executing PSAD Specific Configuration
NOTE:    Executing File Permissions Specific Configuration
NOTE:    Executing Account Security Specific Configuration
NOTE:    Executing Boot Security Specific Configuration
ERROR:   Unable to open /etc/inittab as the
      swap file /etc/inittab.bastille
      already exists.  Rename the swap file to allow Bastille
      to make desired file modifications.
ERROR:   open /etc/inittab.bastille failed...
ERROR:   open /etc/inittab failed.
ERROR:   Couldn't insert line to /etc/inittab, since open failed.NOTE:   Executing Inetd Specific Configuration
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the /var/log/Bastille/error-log file for the output. Not certain that Bastille failed, but do know that you probably will not see /etc/inittab in the uBuntu 12.04 out-of-the-box configuration. Think that may exist in RPM-based distribution (Fedora, Red Hat, SuSE, etc.) but not so sure about that being in Ubuntu any more.

More than likely, parts of your configuration worked, just some parts did not work as expected. You should also take heed of the warnings within the Community documentation about Bastille Linux:

"IMPORTANT: Please be aware that Bastille Linux requires advanced knowledge, is site-specific and has several options that no longer apply to Ubuntu."

found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BastilleLinux).

Might be useful to start with the log output and see if maybe some of the options specified were not applicable to Ubuntu at present.

Have a nice day,

freecode

Comment: Thank you... i see, so ubuntu was a bit different files then what bastille expected. Thanks so much